# [ROS2]can't load parameters from yaml file when migrating ros1 to ros2

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, yaml, parameters, ros-foxy

I'm trying to migrate VINS-Mono(https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/VINS-Mono) to ROS2 version, and now there's a problem with reading parameters. I just modified the ROS1 code of reading parameters to functions usable in ROS2, and I'm not sure whether it's correct.
Here's the modified code of reading config file:

```
... 
template <typename T>
T readParam(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr n, std::string name)
{
    T ans;
    if (n->get_parameter(name, ans))
    {
      std::cout<<"Loaded "<< name << ": " << ans << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout<< "failed to load " << name <<std::endl;
      std::cout << "ans=" << ans << std::endl;
      rclcpp::shutdown();
    }
    return ans;
}

void readParameters(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr n)
{

  std::string config_file;
  config_file = readParam<std::string>(n, "config_file");
  cv::FileStorage fsSettings(config_file, cv::FileStorage::READ);
  if(!fsSettings.isOpened())
  {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Wrong path to settings" << std::endl;
  }

  fsSettings["imu_topic"] >> IMU_TOPIC;
  std::cout << "imu topic: " << IMU_TOPIC << std::endl;

  SOLVER_TIME = fsSettings["max_solver_time"];
  NUM_ITERATIONS = fsSettings["max_num_iterations"];
  MIN_PARALLAX = fsSettings["keyframe_parallax"];
  MIN_PARALLAX = MIN_PARALLAX / FOCAL_LENGTH;

  std::string OUTPUT_PATH;
  fsSettings["output_path"] >> OUTPUT_PATH;
  VINS_RESULT_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH + "/vins_result_no_loop.csv";
  std::cout << "result path " << VINS_RESULT_PATH << std::endl;

  // create folder if not exists
  FileSystemHelper::createDirectoryIfNotExists(OUTPUT_PATH.c_str());

  std::ofstream fout(VINS_RESULT_PATH, std::ios::out);
  fout.close();

  ACC_N = fsSettings["acc_n"];
  ACC_W = fsSettings["acc_w"];
  GYR_N = fsSettings["gyr_n"];
  GYR_W = fsSettings["gyr_w"];
  G.z() = fsSettings["g_norm"];
  ROW = fsSettings["image_height"];
  COL = fsSettings["image_width"];
  ROS_INFO("ROW: %f COL: %f ", ROW, COL);
  ROS_INFO("acc_n: %f acc_w: %f ", ACC_N, ACC_W);

  ESTIMATE_EXTRINSIC = fsSettings["estimate_extrinsic"];
  if (ESTIMATE_EXTRINSIC == 2)
  {
      ROS_WARN("have no prior about extrinsic param, calibrate extrinsic param");
      RIC.push_back(Eigen::Matrix3d::Identity());
      TIC.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d::Zero());
      EX_CALIB_RESULT_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH + "/extrinsic_parameter.csv";

  }
  else 
  {
      if ( ESTIMATE_EXTRINSIC == 1)
      {
          ROS_WARN(" Optimize extrinsic param around initial guess!");
          EX_CALIB_RESULT_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH + "/extrinsic_parameter.csv";
      }
      if (ESTIMATE_EXTRINSIC == 0)
          ROS_WARN(" fix extrinsic param ");

      cv::Mat cv_R, cv_T;
      fsSettings["extrinsicRotation"] >> cv_R;
      fsSettings["extrinsicTranslation"] >> cv_T;
      //std::cout << "cv_R:" << cv_R << std::endl;
      Eigen::Matrix3d eigen_R;
      Eigen::Vector3d eigen_T;
      cv::cv2eigen(cv_R, eigen_R);
      cv::cv2eigen(cv_T, eigen_T);
      Eigen::Quaterniond Q(eigen_R);
      eigen_R = Q.normalized();
      RIC.push_back(eigen_R);
      TIC.push_back(eigen_T);
      ROS_INFO("Extrinsic_R : {}", RIC[0]);
      std::cout << "Extrinsic_R :" << std::endl << RIC[0] << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Extrinsic_T :" << std::endl << TIC[0] << std::endl;
      //ROS_INFO("Extrinsic_T : ", TIC[0].transpose());
    
  } 

  INIT_DEPTH = 5.0;
  BIAS_ACC_THRESHOLD = 0.1;
  BIAS_GYR_THRESHOLD = 0.1;

  TD = fsSettings["td"];
  ESTIMATE_TD = fsSettings["estimate_td"];
  if (ESTIMATE_TD)
      ROS_INFO("Unsynchronized sensors, online estimate time offset, initial td: ", TD);
  else
      ROS_INFO("Synchronized sensors, fix time offset: ", TD);

  ROLLING_SHUTTER = fsSettings["rolling_shutter"];
  if (ROLLING_SHUTTER)
  {
      TR = fsSettings["rolling_shutter_tr"];
      ROS_INFO("rolling shutter camera, read out time per line: ", TR);
  }
  else
  {
      TR = 0;
  }

  fsSettings.release();
}
```

In order to run all three nodes I choose to use ros2 launch command. Here is the launch.py file(I'm also totally new to ros2 launch file).

```
import os
import sys

import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'config_path',
         default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('feature_tracker'),'..','config','euroc','euroc_config.yaml')
    ),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'vins_path',
        default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('feature_tracker'),'..','config','..')
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='feature_tracker',
        executable='feature_tracker',
        name='feature_tracker',
        output='log',
        parameters=[
            {
                'config_file': launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('config_path')
            },
            {
                'vins_folder': launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('vins_path')
            }
        ]
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='vins_estimator',
        executable='vins_estimator_node',
        name='vins_estimator',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[
            {
                'config_file': launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('config_path')
            },
            {
                'vins_folder': launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('vins_path')
            }
        ]
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='pose_graph',
        executable='pose_graph',
        name='pose_graph',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[
            {
                'config_file': launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('config_path')
            },
            {
                'visualization_shift_x': '0'
            },
            {
                'visualization_shift_y': '0'
            },
            {
                'skip_cnt': '0'
            },
            {
                'skip_dis': '0'
            }
        ]
    )
])
return ld


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_launch_description()
```

There may be something wrong with the path of the config file, but it should not be the key problem because I have tried to change it to absolute path but there's still error occurred. The error information looks like:

> [vins_estimator_node-2] [INFO] [1692347457.201213834] []: init begins
>
> [vins_estimator_node-2] failed to load config_file

The output shows that error seems to occur at readParam function. BTW, the yaml file is still in ROS1 format, but I don't have any idea about how to change it to ROS2 version because it's kinds of complicating. If I want to launch this program, is that necessary?